# Demonstrating Immutability and Transparency in a Blockchain: Observing Data Retrieval Across Nodes

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, sepolia, immutability

I have developed a decentralized application (DApp) on a blockchain platform and I'm keen on verifying the fundamental principles of immutability and transparency that blockchain technology offers. Specifically, I would like to witness the process of data retrieval across different nodes in the network when changes are made to the blockchain data. This experiment aims to validate the immutability of the blockchain, where historical records remain unaltered, and the transparency that ensures data changes are openly visible to all participants.

Could someone guide me through the steps to simulate and observe this process effectively? I want to ensure that any modifications to the data are promptly reflected across the network and understand how consensus is maintained. Additionally, I'm interested in understanding how the decentralized nature of the blockchain network prevents unauthorized alterations. Any insights, tools, or methodologies to conduct this experiment would be greatly appreciated.